# Excel VBA Expected Array

Tags: vba, excel

I have three blocks of code, all identical except the variables they reference. However, the "Wrep" block is complaining of a compile error on Wrep_match saying "Expected Array". I can't see any difference between the Wrep and Orep blocks:

```
        If Orep_name = "" Then
            If reps.exists(Orep_number) Then
                Orep_match = Split(reps(Orep_number), ",")
                If IsArray(Orep_match) Then
                    Orep_name = Orep_match(0)
                    Orep_team = Orep_match(1)
                End If
            End If
        End If

        If Wrep_number <> "" And Wrep_number <> "0" Then
            If reps.exists(Wrep_number) Then
                Wrep_match = Split(reps(Wrep_number), ",")
                If IsArray(Wrep_match) Then
                    Wrep_name = Wrep_match(0)
                    Wrep_team = Wrep_match(1)
                End If
            End If
        End If
```

Comment: What is the value of `Wrep_number`?

Comment: Wrep_number is a 1-4 character string. "reps" is a Scripting.Dictionary object.

Comment: Strange . Can you test `LBound` and `UBound` of Wrep_match? You just established it was an array... So I am puzzled with you. Can you give an example of the input  string that caused the failure?

Comment: So you expect to find a comma in your string?

Comment: It's a compile error. "Expected array". It's not even attempting to execute it.

Comment: Yes The string is made up as: reps.Add rep_id, rep_name & "," & rep_team

Comment: What is the value of `Wrep_number` when it fails?

Comment: aphoria: It's a compile error

Comment: VBA is not compiled. Where is this error appearing?

Comment: When I press "Run Sub/UserForm (F5)" it pop's up with a message box titled "Microsoft Visual Basic" that states Compile Error: Expected array

Comment: Do you have the `Wrep_match` variable `DIM`med somewhere above this code? If so, what does that line look like?

Comment: Aphoria: Thanks, just noticed that. "Answered my own question" here. I had declared Wrep_match as a Boolean. I had also declared Srep_match and Orep_match as Booleans so I'm not sure why they were uneffected, but regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error. Nothing to do with the code included. Further up in the Sub I had declared Srep_match, Orep_match, Wrep_match as Boolean. Not sure what Srep_match and Orep_match weren't effected, but it was catching Wrep_match as not being an Array.

Comment: If you do this `Dim a, b, c as Boolean` in VBA then only `c` is a boolean: `a` and `b` are Variant.